# Selenium not running from within a Django App

Tags: django, selenium, pythonanywhere

I am trying to create a web-scraping tool with a Djnago app as a GUI.

I have been able to get selenium up and running on my PythonAnywhere account by following the instructions on [this thread](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/forums/topic/863/) . ie. When I open a python console from command line, and run my scripts it works fine.

However when I try to run the exact same code from within a Django app running on PythonAnywhere I get the following error:

WebDriverException:
Message: The browser appears to have exited before we could connect. If you specified a log_file in the FirefoxBinary constructor, check it for details.

**Update:**
I just tried doing the same thing from the Djnago app on my local machine, and here it did work. I am using Selenium 2.53.6 on both systems. Django 1.10.2 locally and 1.10.3 on PythonAnywhere.

Update 2: Now I'm running Django 1.10.2 in both places, still same problem.

Comment: that's because your server is running on a headless enviorenment. Search for firefox headless or chrome headless.

Comment: PythonAnywhere developer here -- did it work once and then start failing?  Sometimes people write selenium web-scraping code on PythonAnywhere that leaves Xvfb or Firefox running after it exits (you need to make sure to close them properly) and so they hit their process limit and all future attempts fail with that error.  This blog post shows how to close things down properly: https://blog.pythonanywhere.com/3/

Comment: @GilesThomas I never had it work from within the Django App. When I was running from a bash console I was careful to close the Xvfb process when I was done, as outlined in that post on the forum.

Comment: OK, sounds like it certainly *should* work, then :-)  It'll probably be easiest to debug this if you drop us a line at support@pythonanywhere.com, with your username and the name of the website causing the problem -- then we can log in to the appropriate web server and see what's going on.